# Magento discount price round up issue

Tags: magento-1.9

Facing very annoying Magento pricing issue, I have a product with price $634 and promotion rule set to 35% discount. After discount price should show $612.10 but Magento skipping 0.10 it round up to $612 (it skips only 0.10, it works fine in other cases i.e $612.25, $612.95 etc) any help?

Comment: have you solve this problem..??

Comment: Yeah it was my bad actually there were two promotion rules created for same product that were causing issue I just deleted one of them and its works.